# How to represent percentage values in Matlab

Tags: matlab

is there any easy way to represent percentage values in Matlab 
for example as in excel we can type 8% and it will represent 0.08. the % symbol is suffix to the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

`a = '%.2f%%';`

%.2f%% will show the percentage to 2 decimal places and add a % at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Since the percent character is part of the string formatting syntax, you have to escape it if you want to output its literal:

```
p = 0.08;
txt = sprintf('%.0f%%',p*100)

txt =
      '8%'
```

For more information, read [this page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html) of the official Matlab documentation.